# "Take up" more work semantically correct?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is it correct to say that someone will "take up more work" when they mean they will start working on tasks that are already scheduled to be worked on?

Comment: Have you tried consulting a good English language dictionary?  Look at 4b, here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take-up

Comment: I haven't come across **take up more work**. The expression **take on more work** is used to mean to accept or commit to work additional to one's current workload or duties. **Take up** is more often heard in respect of an activity, often a hobby or sport - **take up dancing / soccer.**.

Comment: @RonaldSole But you have certainly come across **take up the slack**, and since *the slack* means *work* in that metaphor, you wouldn't necessarily be confused if someone said *work* directly